# How to convert time and date string to ISO format

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have two inputs, a time and a date input. I'm trying to format them as an ISO string to send to the backend using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

This is what I have so far `01:00 2016-01-01`, I need to format or convert that to ISO. Is there a way to do it using Moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to ISO8601 and [momentjs](http://momentjs.com) (2.10.6), I currently do it like this

```
var example = momentObject.format("YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 3):

To convert ISO I recommend the more standard

```
date.format();
```

or

```
JSON.stringify(yourDate)
```

or if you prefer momentjs:

```
var date = moment();
date.toISOString();
```

or

```
moment(yourDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY'); // <- your custom format string
```

To know what are the momentjs formatting rules [start reading here](http://momentjs.com/docs/)

Comment: These are two separate values I need to concatenate then convert. When I run ```JSON.stringify(concatString)``` it just returns my string with extra quotes.

Comment: Well, you must first parse the result to either native date or a moment.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use moment's parse function to first create the correct moment object from the data that you have (assuming a 24-hour clock, and month listed before the days):

```
var myMoment = moment("01:00 2016-01-01", "HH:mm YYYY-MM-DD");
```

Then you can use moment's format function to output the date in the ISO format that you want. Note that calling the format function without any parameters will output ISO 8601 by default:

```
myMoment.format();
```

See the moment docs for more info [here](http://momentjs.com/docs/).

Hope this helps!